# Simple list iteration addition not working

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have some scores that are in a list "points". I want to use this list to create another list "progress" where each item is the progressive sum of items in "points".

This is the "points" list:

```
points = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

This is how the "progress" list should look:

```
progress = [1, 3, 6, 7, 7, 9]
```

Here is my code, that doesn't work:

```
points = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]
progress = []
start = []
for i in points:
    start += [i]
    progress.append(start)
print("progrress: ")
print(progress[0])
```

The result I get when I run the code is:

```
progrress: 
[1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Obviously I am missing something simple but I can't find it.

Comment: Remember that you can always rely on list comprehensions for such things like: `[sum(points[:i+1]) for i in range(len(points))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[points]` creates a list from `points` which is already a list, so your loop iterates over `[[1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]]`, i.e. it does only 1 iteration where `i = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]`. You don't need these extra `[]`!

Same goes for `start`, it should be an integer.

You'll also want to increment `start` before appending it to `progress`.

Comment: Thanks Jules. But when I remove the [] around points, I get the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: OK. I've mover "start" to before the append and removed the [] around "points". But it just churns out a duplicate of the "points" list.

Comment: start should also be an integer (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code. Give it a try

```
points = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2]
progress = []

for i in range(len(points)):
    progress.append(sum(points[0:i+1:]))

print progress
```

This prints `[1, 3, 6, 7, 7, 9]` as per your expectation